# How to upload multiple images from different fields in VueJs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

vuejs file

```
<v-form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div v-if="!loading">
            <v-card-text headline><h1>Please upload your documents</h1></v-card-text>
            <v-layout row class="pt-1">
              <v-flex xs12>
                <v-subheader>Photo A</v-subheader>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex xs12>
                <input id="photoA" type="file" accept="image/*">
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-layout row>
              <v-flex xs12>
                <v-subheader>Photo B</v-subheader>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex xs12>
                <input id="photo B" type="file" accept="image/*">
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-layout row>
              <v-flex xs12>
                <v-subheader class="text-sm-left">Photo C Statement</v-subheader>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex xs12>
                <input id="photoC" type="file" accept="image/*">
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <div v-html="error" />
            <div>
              <v-btn round block color="blue darken-3" dark large @click="submitDocs">Upload</v-btn>
            </div>
            </div>
          </v-form>
```

script

```
submitDocs () {
  console.log("submit docs clicked!")
  const formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('myFile', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name)
  axios.post('my-domain.com/file-upload', formData)
}
```

I am stucked in writing `submitDocs`. How do I do axios.post with photoA, photoB and photoC ? How do I get the file of photoA, photoB and photoC and upload it via axios.post ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would try to pass in the form element into the constructor `new FormData(formElm)` then everything in the form will be copied into `formData`

Comment: <input data-v-314a5c28="" id="photoA" type="file" accept="image/*"> how do I get the data of photoA and upload it ? @Endless

Comment: something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/v0gsdyao/9/

Answer (score 1):

`v-model` is not supported on `input[type=file]` so you need to write your own handler for each input:

```
<input id="photoA" type="file" accept="image/*" @change="addFile('photoA', $event)">
...
<input id="photoA" type="file" accept="image/*" @change="addFile('photoB', $event)">
...
<input id="photoA" type="file" accept="image/*" @change="addFile('photoC', $event)">
```

Implementation of handler may look like this:

```
methods: {
  addFile(fileKey, event) {
    this[fileKey] = event.target.files[0];
    console.log('File added', fileKey, event.target.files[0]);
  },
}
```

Append each file to `FormData`

```
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('photoA', this.photoA, this.photoA.name)
formData.append('photoB', this.photoB, this.photoB.name)
formData.append('photoC', this.photoC, this.photoC.name)
axios.post('my-domain.com/file-upload', formData)
```

But this approach is good only if you have a few pictures. If you'd like to use it for many images it's better to store then in array. E.g.

```
const formData = new FormData();
// let's say you have array of files in your `this.photos`
this.photos.map(photo => formData.append('photos[]', photo, photo.name);
axios.post('my-domain.com/file-upload', formData)
```

---

Simple demo is here https://codesandbox.io/s/kx7y3knvjr